# What is the term for "a" or "An" in sentence structure

Tags: indefinite-article, determiners, terminology

In the English language, there seems to be a term for any word that shows up in a sentence; be it a noun, verb, adjective, etc. What's the correct term for "a" or "an" in a sentence? This is actually much harder to Google than it sounds due to Google stripping out simple words such as "a" and "an".

Comment: The terms, as a group, are known as the parts of speech, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those words are known as *indefinite articles* — "indefinite" because they don't refer to a specific/particular thing, like the *definite article*, "the", does. They *do* refer to an *individual* thing; it's just not any particular one that's been singled out previously.

There are also so-called *zero articles*. These show up when no word at all is used as an article, such as before "so-called" in the previous sentence, which could have been worded as "There is also a so-called […]". This is usually to indicate a *group*, rather than an *individual*. (Both definite and indefinite articles, while usually referring to an individual thing, can be used to refer to an individual *characterizing a group*, and therefore to the group as a whole by extension.)

"Some" is sometimes considered an article as well, as in "He had some ninety-nine answers."

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: @Refutinglogic: While I'm certainly grateful for the checkmark, you might want to [wait a while longer before settling down](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: I think the first paragraph is excellent.  The second para could do with much more clarity.  I'd never heard of *zero articles* before, and am very interested.  However I don't feel any more *informed* about them, even after reading the paragraph about them.

Comment: @EuanM: Hmm. Hopefully that's better. I originally intended merely to introduce the names, but I guess it makes sense to very briefly summarize their function as well.

Comment: -1 *A/an* is called the indefinite article because it does not make a *definite* reference (hence its name). It can, however, make a specific reference. *I just bought a new car and I'm driving it home* is an indefinite, specific reference to this 'particular thing', that is to this 'particular and specific car'.

Comment: @NES: Is that clearer?

Comment: I suggest section 5.2.2. (page 94) in [this grammar](https://books.google.com/books?id=lx7UAniLfJwC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=indefinite+reference+grammar&source=bl&ots=_gIauHX1wD&sig=ESIYiLiQDkwDk7OHT1rAp-lgesw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisx_CfrcHJAhWEPD4KHfGuDX4Q6AEILTAG#v=onepage&q=indefinite%20reference%20grammar&f=false) to see that an indefinite reference can be *either specific or nonspecific.* The surrounding sections seem great as well.

Comment: @NES: That doesn't seem to contradict my point, although I suppose my choice of terminology could be improved, as they use "specific" a little differently. I'll see if I can work on that. But the example given of "an American in Kalamazoo" is *not* referring to a particular American *previously* singled out -- rather, that *is* the singling out, right there.